# Which schema does the store procedure run? the owner's schema or caller's schema?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I found the question.

- user B has a store procedure "B.pk.sp", and user A can reads the
  "B.pk.sp" and executes it.
- The procedure "B.pk.sp" manipulates the tables without schema belong
  to user B.

That makes me confused is that if the user A calls the "B.sk.sp" will manipulate the user B table or it will manipuate the user A table?

Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: I think it depends of [Grant/Revoke Privileges](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/grant_revoke.php)

Comment: It depends on whether the b.pk.sp procedure has been compiled with [definer's or invoker's rights](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/dr_ir.htm#DBSEG99925). If it's with definer's rights (the default), then the procedure will run with user B's privileges (i.e. it'll use the tables in schema B), otherwise it'll run with the invoking user's privileges.

Comment: In Oracle, when you access an object, the engine will automatically search for objects belonging to the user(schema), and next, to public synonyms. So, in theory, if user A calls B.sk.sp, it will manipulate user A table. But there may be several other things that may change this behavior (login triggers, privileges,.....), so you need to test it.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso That is incorrect (with regard to the default schema a procedure will use) - the [default](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm#i2065815) is for a procedure to be defined with `AUTHID DEFINER` as the invoker rights; so if user `A` calls `B.procedure_name` (or `B.package_name.procedure_name`) then that procedure will manipulate tables in `B`'s schema. It is only if you specify `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` as the invoker rights that it will try to manipulate tables in the invoking user's (`A`'s) schema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the [invoker rights clause (i.e. `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm) set when you define the procedure.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE USER A IDENTIFIED BY APassword;
CREATE USER B IDENTIFIED BY BPassword;

CREATE TABLE A.your_table ( id ) AS SELECT 'A' FROM DUAL;
CREATE TABLE B.your_table ( id ) AS SELECT 'B' FROM DUAL;

CREATE PROCEDURE A.test_invoker_rights( id OUT VARCHAR2 ) AUTHID CURRENT_USER
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT id INTO id FROM your_table WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
END;
/
GRANT EXECUTE ON A.test_invoker_rights TO B;
```

Now consider the PL/SQL script:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  ID VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
  A.test_invoker_rights(id);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(id);
END;
/
```

If you run it as user `A` then the output is `A`; but if you run it as user `B` then the output is `B`.

Now, if you redefine the procedure to have the header:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A.test_invoker_rights( id OUT VARCHAR2 ) AUTHID DEFINER
```

or with the default invoker's rights (by omitting that clause):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A.test_invoker_rights( id OUT VARCHAR2 )
```

Then if you run it as user `A` then the output is `A`; but if you run it as user `B` then the output would still be `A`.

The default is `AUTHID DEFINER` and the procedure (or package) would manipulate tables in its owner's schema (and not the invoker's schema).

Comment: And if you really want to localise the edits/operations to one particular user/schema, you can use synonyms or explicitly mention username.object

Comment: @RogueCoder yes... but the question was that "the procedure manipulates the tables **without schema**"; so specifying the schema invalidates the premise of the question.